# Activation Functions in Haykins Neural Networks a comprehensive foundation

Tags: neural-network, activation-function

In Haykins Neural Network a comprehensive foundation, the piecwise-linear funtion is one of the described activation functions.
It is described with:
[image]

The corresponding shown plot is 
[image]

I don't really understand how this is corrected since the values shown in the graph in the area of -0.5 < v < 0.5 is not v but v+0.5.
Am I understanding something wrong, or is there a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake.

I think there should be `v + 0.5` in the function definition, since the author set boundaries as `1` and `0`.